# Update table DB in Laravel with findOrNew

Tags: database, laravel, sql-update, laravel-controller, laravel-datatables

How I can update table in DB, with use function findOrNew
I want first check column in table. If I have same title not add, if I dont have - push
I campare @title@ in table DB.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{$news = News::findOrNew($request->title);
    if($news->title==$request->title){

    }else{
        $news->'title'=$request->input('title');
    };
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO ... I think you are looking for `firstOrNew` not `findOrNew` which is used for searching on the primary key specifically.

```
$news = News::firstOrNew(['title' => $request->input('title')]);
```

`$news` will be the existing record that has a 'title' that matches the request input or it will be a new instance with the 'title' set to the value you were searching for.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want check title. If I have title in table DB - return @mistake@, if dont have - add news in table

Comment: this is doing what you think you are attempting to do in your example ... it is searching the database for a matching record, if it can't find one it gives you a new instance with the values filled

Comment: oh, I understand. I dont need made check.